# Drools, how to check if an object appears only once in a list

Tags: drools

I have a number of someObjects in my working memory and i want to write a rule in which check if one object is appeared twice in in these objects. (it is not a list, it is only a number of individual objects in the working memory)

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this at least with `collect` as

```
when
  $n: ArrayList( size > 1 ) from collect( SomeObject() )
then:
  // do some action
end
```

You can also have conditions for which of SomeObjects you want to match.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply, now i have problem with contains and not contains in drools ... do you by any chance have a sample of contains for a list of someObjects?

Comment: is this expression wrong: eval (!($someList.contains(SomeObjectEntity(accossiation.type == Type.Legal))));

Comment: @mana aything you write inside an eval is evaluated as Java expression, so you cannot write your condition like that. That condition could also be written with collect as `... from collect( SomeObjectEntity( association.type == Type.Legal ) )` and check size of ArrayList as above. There might be an easier way, though, but can't think of any at the moment.

Comment: could you please help me with the query? the rule is: one someObject must appear once in listOfSomeObjects list.

Comment: It is usually not possible to have the same object twice in working memory, because it does not make sense to have the same fact twice. (A truth doesn't become any truer by repeating it.)

Comment: @kaskelotti Your rule does not achieve what OP was asking. It fires when there is more than one SomeObject, irrespective of their contents.

Comment: @manamandegar Your comments asking for another rule are utterly confusing. Start a new question.

Comment: I didn't mean literally exact same objects ... I am starting a new thread for this question

Comment: @laune the original question was to know whether one object appears twice. It does not state anything about equality and I have interpreted it as an instance of a fact check. I also added a note after the code example of using a constraint, and which is actually shown in my comment later on when OPs requirements are better known.

Comment: @kaskelotti It may be that the original question is badly formulated, but then you can't answer by posting some code which does not do what the question asks.